# .gitignore problems: Cannot ignore some sub folders

Tags: git

I have faced with one problem in configuring of .gitignore file where I want to ignore some subfolders.

That`s my git status:

modified:   .gitignore
modified:   Client/Android/Cafe/out/production/Cafe/Cafe.apk

modified:   Client/Android/Cafe/out/production/Cafe/Cafe.unaligned.apk

I want to ignore everything that is inside of "out" folder, and "out" folder ignore too.(I target your attention on that my .gitignore file is out of Cafe folder, it`s in the root)

I have alredy tried to write in .gitignore next notes:

**/out

/Client/Android/Cafe/out

/Client/Android/**/out

/Client/Android/Cafe/out/*

But nothing helps me, where is my mistake?

#### EDIT:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   Client/Android/Cafe/.idea/misc.xml
#       modified:   Client/Android/Cafe/.idea/vcs.xml
#       modified:   Client/Android/Cafe/.idea/workspace.xml
#       modified:   Client/Android/Cafe/gen/enthusiasts/apps/Cafe/BuildConfig.ja
va
#       modified:   Client/Android/Cafe/gen/enthusiasts/apps/Cafe/Manifest.java
#       modified:   Client/Android/Cafe/gen/enthusiasts/apps/Cafe/R.java
#       modified:   Client/Android/Cafe/out/production/Cafe/Cafe.apk
#       modified:   Client/Android/Cafe/out/production/Cafe/Cafe.unaligned.apk
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       .gitignore
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Thanks all of you for trying to help me but it doesn`t help me. May be, it should be inside stage state or whatever else stage? Somewhy .gitignore works only for root folder but not for all subfolders.

Comment: https://github.com/github/gitignore

Comment: The rule `/Client/Android/Cafe/out` should work.

Comment: It would appear that you need to 'git add .gitignore' and `git commit'...

Comment: possible duplicate of [.gitignore file not ignoring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/gitignore-file-not-ignoring)

Answer (score 1):

If the files from the folder has been already versionned, you need to remove them first from git with `git rm -r --cached Client/Android/Cafe/out/`

Otherwise, this syntax is correct:

**.gitignore**

```
Client/Android/Cafe/out
```

Comment: `git` doesn't track folders/directories. If it won't ignore a directory, it's because that directory contains files that are tracked, not because the directory is tracked.